# Deny write to Everyone blocking also read access (icacls)

Tags: security, batch-file, windows-10, icacls

I'm trying to deny only write access to some folders using:

```
icacls "C:\Temp\otentu\*" /deny Everyone:(OI)(CI)(W)
```

In effect I can't also open subfolders. When I doing this same via UI I can open them.

So after running this command when I go "Permissions" screen and just uncheck/check Deny Write and click OK I can open this folder and list items. There is no differences in checked items on "Advanced permissions" tab after this action.

`C:\Temp\otentu\` is main folder with 2 subfolders, and we have two stories here:

1. Using UI I'm addig Deny Write to Everyone for one subfolder.
2. I'm calling above `icacls`.
   Screenshot is showing that result of both of them is this same for this folder - other settings are untouched. After 1 I can open subfolder, after 2 I can't.

Can someone help what I missing here?

[image: 1]

**EDIT**:
I run `icacls "C:\Temp\otentu" /T /C /L /Q` for each scenario - no difference at all. To simplify I left only one subfolder.

BEFORE:

```
C:\Temp\otentu BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
               BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
               NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
               NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

C:\Temp\otentu\dwa BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                   BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
                   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
                   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
```

AFTER UI CHANGES:

```
C:\Temp\otentu BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
               BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
               NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
               NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

C:\Temp\otentu\dwa Everyone:(OI)(CI)(DENY)(W)
                   BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                   BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
                   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
                   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
```

AFTER CMD:

```
C:\Temp\otentu BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
               BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
               NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
               NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

C:\Temp\otentu\dwa Everyone:(OI)(CI)(DENY)(W)
                   BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                   BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
                   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
                   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
```

Comment: Are you sure your question is about an issue with the command, or rather an understanding of how to achieve the task of denying a particular permission, whilst allowing others. I think that it would be advisable if you were to provide a proper explanation/view of all of the permissions currently in effect on your target directory and its respective children; one for those as a result of your provided code; and one for your intended result.

Comment: @Compo I did some edits, maybe now will be more clear

Comment: No, you've shown an image of a single directory only, with one single permission set to deny, and none set to allow. You have not indicated anything about any of the permissions inherited or otherwise of any of the current or intended content of that directory or clarified if that image is the result of your submitted code. It would be almost malpractice for us to advise you on someting which could essentially lock everyone out of control of one or more file/directory objects, based upon what you've shown.

Comment: C:\Temp\otentu\ is main folder with 2 subfolders, and we have two stories here:
1. Using UI I'm addig Deny Write to Everyone for one subfolder.
2. I'm calling above `icacls`.
Screenshot is showing that result of both of them is this same for this folder - other settings are untouched. After 1 I can open subfolder, after 2 I can't.

Comment: It seems to me as if your issue is not with code, but an understanding of how to use the tool. Why don't you start by using `icacls "C:\Temp\otentu" /T /C /L /Q >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\before.log"`. Then make your changes in the GUI. When that is complete, run `icacls "C:\Temp\otentu" /T /C /L /Q >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\after.log"`. Now you should have two log files you can use to compare the differences between those two states. Once you have those, you may be able to better understand the options you'll need when you perform the task GUI free.

Comment: I did it. To simplify I left only one subfolder. There are no differences. In scenario with icacls I'm getting error that I don't have permissions when trying open subfolder.